# Customed ASP.NET Error Message not showing

Tags: c#, asp.net

I followed [this tutorial](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/Tip_2F00_Trick_3A00_-Show-Detailed-Error-Messages-to-Developers) to create a custom error page. But I only have a white page and the URL isn't my error page. In my web.config file, I added:

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/friendlyErrorPage.htm"/>
```

But it doesn't work... I launched an error by deleting some columns in my database.

For now, I just want to show a page when there is an error, I don't care about your role, just a generic page.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:
I used log4net to send error by mails. I commented the code in application_error and it works! Which line is the problem?

```
String err = Server.GetLastError().ToString();
Exception ex = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();
log.Error(err, ex);
Server.ClearError();
```

Comment: You test it on remonte machine, or locally?

Comment: For now, locally but when it will work on remote

Comment: `customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"` say show this error page only to remonte connections, local connections gets normal error page.

Comment: look at F12 developer tools to see what URL is redirected

Comment: In fact, the URL I have is the 'not working' page. I click on a link to a page, then it doesn't work (that's normal) but then I have a white page and the URL is the page I clicked on. No redirection...

Comment: If you click bad link, why error page should appear? Error page appear in case error in your app, bad link isn't internal error it's browser error.

Comment: Change the mode to On to activate the redirection [Custom Errors Element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: The link usualy works but some informations should be displayed on this new page and those informations are unavailable because I deleted them.(to create an error) An error is launched because I have one in my solution on VS, but no redirection.

Comment: @Gururaj no, already tried and no difference...

Comment: Add some details like whether you've Application_Error handler in your application's global.aspx file and also what exactly is your observation when some error occurs and you don't see the custom error page.

Comment: I used log4net, look at my EDIT in original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like

```
Server.ClearError();
```

block the error page, it seems to work without this line.